# Memory allocated for char (* arr)[X];

Tags: c, pointers

I'm a little bit lost on what this statement is doing. Is it making an array of X pointers? Or is it a pointer to an array of X chars? How much memory does it take on a 32-bit system?

If its the former, does it take 4*X bytes? If its the latter, is it just 1*X bytes?

Comment: See the [clockwise spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pointer which points to an array of `X` chars.

The C standard does not specify any particular size for a pointer.  On common systems however, pointers are all the same size; so probably 4 bytes on your system.

`X` is part of the size of what is being pointed to, not the size of the pointer itself.

Comment: So, if I run printf("%i",sizeof(arr)); and it returns 4, that is the correct answer?

Comment: @master565 `sizeof` evalutes to a `size_t`   , so you should either use the `%zu` format specifier  ; or cast the result of sizeof to `int` .  There's no single correct answer, different systems may give different answers. You could try it on the system you are interested in.

Comment: Its not too important about which specific system, It's just a general question of how this works. 

So the final answer is just whatever size the system I'm working on uses for pointers, correct? X doesn't matter because we haven't actually created any data to point to?

Comment: @master565 The size of a pointer has nothing to do with whether you have made it point anywhere